# Numpy: Get minimum value indices in array, ignoring specific value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to get the indices of the minimum values in array, such as:

```
ind = np.where((arr == arr.min()))
```

I'd like to modify this so that I can ignore a specific value. e.g:

```
ind = np.where((arr == arr[arr != value].min()))
```

The above solution is ok, but can it be done better?

Comment: meaning faster? or less memory use? ... What size are your arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a masked array and then use `np.where()` on it:

```
m = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask=(a==value))
np.where(m, m==m.min())
```

giving what you want.

Answer (score 2):

use numpys argmin()

```
ind= np.argmin(arr[arr!=value])
```

Comment: `argmin` returns only the first index.